# rspec email validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, email-validation

I'm learning Rspec. When i run my test case for email validation I'm getting an error which am not able to understand.Please explain.

```
  1) User should check for email validation
     Failure/Error: @test_user.should have(1).errors_on(:email)
       expected 1 errors on :email, got 2
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:17:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.12903 seconds
2 examples, 1 failure
```

My test cases are below:

```
  it"should check whether name is present or not" do
    @test_user.name = nil
    @test_user.should have(1).errors_on(:name)
  end

  it "should check for email validation"do
    @test_user.email = nil
    @test_user.should have(2).errors_on(:email)
  end
end
```

Comment: I just re-read your question and I obviously didn't read it thoroughly enough. I might guess that the state of your @test_user isn't getting reset between tests. Can you provide the parts of your spec file that sets this variable up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're validating the email attribute with both the presence validator and some sort of format validator, then you'd get two errors by setting the attribute to nil.

Maybe try something like:

```
validates :email, presence: true, 
                  format: { with: %r\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\Z/,
                            allow_nil: true  }
```